# AWS Glue giving an error: Login failed for user ''

Tags: sql-server, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, etl, aws-glue

I have an AWS Glue job trying to run, and it keeps giving me this error

> An error occurred while calling o117.pyWriteDynamicFrame. Glue ETL Marketplace: failed to retrieve table schema from source.driverClassName: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver, error message: Login failed for user ''.

Under Data Catalog > Connections > Connection Access, I have added my secret.

Inside my secret, I have these fields:

```
user | sa

password |myStrongPassword1

engine | sqlserver

host | RDS-DATABASE-NAME.UNIQUE-STRING.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com

port| 1433

dbInstanceIdentifier | RDS-DATABASE-NAME

username | sa
```

As you can see from above,  have tried both adding user and username fields. I'm not even sure why the error is "Login failed for user '' ", because I have added that my user is 'sa'.